# Scrolling up the content nestedscrollview and show appbarlayout

Tags: android

How I can view the `AppbarLayout` as I scroll up the content of `NestedScrollView` without reaching at the top of the content of `NestedScrollView`.

Comment: Please add some code to explain your problem. Your intention is not very clear. Please be very specific to your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"` to your Toolbar xml.